# Is there a way to update the signaturedef of my tensorflow saved_model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow.js

I trained and exported my TensorFlow model as a saved_model format using Python.

```
serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(
   tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_columns))

linear_est.export_saved_model("modelFromEstimator/", serving_input_fn)
```

and I imported it to nodeJs using TensorFlow node and I tried predicting using

```
async function predict(input) {
    const model = await tfn.node.loadSavedModel("./savedModel/")
                .catch((err) => console.log (err))
    const output = model.predict(input);
    return output
}
const mainput = require("./input.json")

console.log(predict(mainput))
```

but I got an error

```
The model signatureDef input names are inputs, however the provided input names are tagName,isAccessible,hasAccessibilityProperty
```